# Certbot error: No matching distribution found for apache

Tags: apache, lets-encrypt, certbot

After running this command:

```
$ sudo /opt/certbot/bin/certbot renew


ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement apache (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for apache
```

Have installed Certbot as follows:

```
Successfully installed boto3-1.26.154 botocore-1.29.154 certbot-dns-route53-2.6.0 jmespath-1.0.1 python-dateutil-2.8.2 s3transfer-0.6.1 urllib3-1.26.16
```

Comment: Just an aside about voting 'up' or 'down'  -  I believe this post is sufficient for my question.  For the person that correctly answered (and resolved) it was perfect amount of information. I appreciate having this platform to exchange information and inquire about various matters.  Nonetheless, it appears that some users may occasionally exhibit a casual attitude in their responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue seems to be about the Apache plugin.
If you are required to use Certbot with Apache, you should also install the certbot-apache plugin, not the certbot-dns-route53 plugin as shown above.

Here is how to install certbot-apache:

```
sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install certbot-apache
```

try to renew your certificates after the installation.Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, no errors - I spent hours on this and you diagnosed perfectly!  All certs renewed.  Thanks again @Ray John Navarro!